# Rename all arrays in a deeply nested object with nested array of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

I am building a recursive "massage" function that needs to rename certain property keys. I've been trying some recursive methods, but to no avail thus far.

For example, I need to remove the word 'Array' from all of the arrays that are within this deeply nested object.

Sample input:

```
var input = {
  test: {
    testArray1: [
      {
        testArray2: [
          {
            sample: {
              testArray3: [],
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

Expected output:

```
var output = {
  test: {
    test1: [
      {
        test2: [
          {
            sample: {
              test3: [],
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best approach for this (without recursion) can be converting the `JSON` to `string` with `JSON.stringify()`, do some `replace()` operation on the `string`, and convert it back to `JSON` with `JSON.parse()`, like this:

```js
const input = {
  test: {testArray1: [
    {testArray2: [
      {sample: {testArray3: ["Array"],},},
    ],},
  ],},
};

let res = JSON.stringify(input).replace(/(Array)([^:]*):/g, "$2:");
res =  JSON.parse(res);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Very good approach indeed.

Comment: What if the `Array` word is in the values...?

Comment: Thanks, but I learned this from another user (lets call it CP) on another answer when I tried for 30 minutes to respond the question with a recursive approach.

Comment: @YosvelQuintero I updated the regular expression for catch that case.

Comment: What if the Array word followed by a colon is in the values?

Comment: Well, in some special cases I suppose this won't work, it is just a fast approach, but for a full-cover solution I think a recursion procedure should be made.

Comment: @Shidersz Very good answer, thanks

Comment: Wow, clever! This is why I didn't want to specify the method as needing to be recursive. Just needed a quick solution like this.

Comment: @Trevor take into consideration to choice this answer as correct if you consider this solution fits to you.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a "simple" recursive approach that should work for your situation:

```
function removeWord(input, word = "Array") {

  if (Array.isArray(input)) {
    return input.map(obj => removeWord(obj, word));
  } else if (typeof input == "object") {
    var result = {};
    Object.keys(input).forEach(key => {
        result[key.replace(word, "")] = removeWord(input[key]);
    });
    return result;
  } else {
    return input;
  }

}
```

Please be aware that this approach is not very robust (and also quite expensive in terms of memory if your original object is very deep).